# cancelDownload ,context deleteObject - CoreData could not fulfill a fault

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I try to cancel a download process by doing:

```
 //operation -> AFDownloadRequestOperation
  - (void)cancelDownload: (CDVInvokedUrlCommand*) command{
     [[DownloadManager operation] cancel];
     [CoreDataManager deleteFromQueueWithId:[ command.arguments objectAtIndex: 0]];
  }


 + (void) deleteFromQueueWithId: (NSString * ) entryID {
     NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
     NSFetchRequest * request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
     [request setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
     request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName: @"Download"];
     [request setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
     [request setPredicate: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"id=%@", entryID]];
     [request setFetchLimit: 1];

    NSError *err = nil;
    NSArray *array = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&err];

   if (err) {
       return;
    }

  [self deleteFromQueue:[array objectAtIndex:0]];
}

+ (BOOL) deleteFromQueue: (NSManagedObject *)item {
  NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
 NSError *err = nil;

  [context deleteObject:item];
  if (![context save:&err]) {
  //        NSLog(@"Cannot save: %@!", [err localizedDescription]);
      return NO;
  }
  return YES;
}

+ (NSManagedObjectContext *) managedObjectContext {
  AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
  return [delegate managedObjectContext];
}
```

Everything passes okay nut when I am trying to save after delete action I get following error:

CoreData could not fulfill a fault for '0xa687d60

Comment: But what's your goal here? You should explain a little bit what is your context...

Comment: how many threads are calling `cancelDownload:`? what is the implementation of `[CoreDataManager managedObjectContext]`?

Comment: @DanShelly Agree with you. I will delete my answer.

Comment: My goal is to cancel a download I started.
The process:
1. Download starts
2. I store download data in core data
3. Start downloading (file system)

I just want to cancel the download and delete this item from my core data

Comment: There is only one thread which is calling cancelDownload, about command and so on.. I just pass an id and with this id I get NSManagedObject

Comment: managedObjectContext attached

Comment: what is your CoreData stack architecture? is there a background context making the actual save?

Comment: The only 'save' I do is when adding and deleting from data core, in this way:
[context save:&err]

Comment: Ok i think i know where is the problem.
I am calling to AFDownloadRequestOperation cancel:
     [[DownloadManager operation] cancel];
This cancel is the big problem, when i comment this line everything works fine

Comment: This is not a solution, but inorder to track the issue further down, check wheter or not if the NSMangedObject is inserted in your persistent store, berore you delete it. Use NSManagedObject isInserted Boolean.

Comment: Hi Seya,

I have this block: 
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {}

I added:
 if ([operation isCancelled]) {
  return;
}
Now everything looks ok, what you think about it?

Comment: That seems fine, does this help the problem?

Comment: Yes I attached another line and now it looks like:

if ( [operation isCancelled] ) {
            [operation deleteTempFileWithError: &error];
            return;
}

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, as I mentioned when deleting a file I:

1. Cancel the operation process
2. Delete the file from CoreData

When doing 1 without 2 everything works fine (or doing 2 without 1)
My solution was to add an 'isCancelled' condition in 'setCompletionBlockWithSuccess' block,
here is the code:

```
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"File downloaded succesffully!");
    [self reportEndDownload:file withStatusCode:[NSNumber numberWithInt:DOWNLAOD_STATUS_COMPLETE]];
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *reqOperation, NSError *error) {
    //This is the condition which solved my problem
       if ( [operation isCancelled] ) {
          [operation deleteTempFileWithError: &error];
          return;
       }
    }
}];
```

Comment: Please update your question instead of posting as an answear. Thank you.